# TypeScript: Omitting a Function prototype from a type extending () => any

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, prototype

I am creating an API in typescript, and I would like to return a function, which has more functions as properties (one of which is the same function).

To achieve this I have:

```
type MainFunc = () => PublicInterface
type PublicFunction = () => PublicInterface

interface PublicInterface extends MainFunc {
  mainFunc: MainFunc
  anotherFunc: PublicFunction
}

const removeProto = (func: MainFunc) => {
  Object.setPrototypeOf(func, null)
  return func
}

const mainFunc: MainFunc = (): PublicInterface => createPublicInterface()
const anotherFunc: PublicFunction = () => createPublicInterface()

const createPublicInterface = (): PublicInterface =>
  Object.assign(
    removeProto(mainFunc),
    {
      mainFunc,
      anotherFunc
    }
  )
```

In the Javascript code I also remove the prototype of MainFunc (apply, call etc.) as I don't want it used, but for the life of me I cant figure out how to remove it from the type as well.

I have tried various combinations of Omit, Pick etc, but so far nothing.

**Edit:**

I have added more code above to try and give more context. The actual code is far more complex but I hope this displays the problem.

Basically, I have a public interface on a function. In the real code, the 'MainFunction' changes based on context, but it always returns another function with public interface so the user can chain.

I manually remove the prototype form the main function, and then assign the public interface to it.

This all works fine and dandy in JS alone, and the types work fine if I don't remove the prototype. I just cant get Typescript to understand a function with bespoke properties, and without that I cant supply accurate intellisense.

***What I have managed so far with my tinkering:***

A type that has my PublicInterface on it, but it doesn't know its also a function itself.

A type that knows its a function, and that has my public interface on it but has all the Function.prototype props (apply, call etc) set to never. In this case they still all show in intellisense which is not a good user experience.
[image: Don't want this]

**If people are voting to close the question, would you mind explaining why so I can do something about it, as opposed to just clicking from the shadows with no explanation?**

Comment: Could you share the JS you're trying to provide types for? That would make it easier to understand the types you need to write.

Comment: Also, can you provide the types for `Arg` and `Ret`? Also the `ReturnType` identifier is already taken by TypeScript. You might want to pick a different name.

Comment: Does this work for you?  `type FunkyFunc<T extends Function> = T & { [K in keyof Function]?: never };`  If so I might be able to make an answer for you, but a [mcve] in your question would be helpful.  Good luck!

Comment: @DerrickBeining - thanks for your comments. Yes, sorry ReturnType was a silly thing to call it. It was just for the pseudo code here, not in the actual code. The type for the arguments does not seem to be relevant to this problem. Please let me know if I'm wrong about that. Mostly they are ...rest args of one sort or another. I have made edits now.

Comment: @jcalz - Hmm interesting. Could you expand that to a function that takes some typable argument, and which returns another function with bespoke props?
I have added more info to the question.

Comment: @jcalz - I tried using your type thusly: 
interface PublicInterface extends FunkyFunc<MainFunc>

But intellisense still shows the full prototype. I have already managed to get to a point already where the prototype shows, but everything is set to never. This is not ideal either though really.

Comment: @jcalz - Sorry that wasn't very clear - Yours did set everything to never, but I don't even want it set to that. I managed to achieve this already, although your method was far nice than mine.

Comment: TS isn't geared toward messing with the type definitions of built-in global types... all callable types implicitly get a `Function` interface. You can extend `Function`, but that only allows *narrowings* (like setting properties to `never`) and not *widenings* (like omitting properties). So as far as I know there's no way to do what you're asking. I could make this into an answer if you want. In any case, please consider editing your example code to constitute a [mcve], ideally which can be dropped into a standalone IDE like [The Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org) with no errors.

Comment: @jcalz - Thanks for your comment. 
Well if that's true, it is only so in the case of functions. If you create an object and then type it with an interface, the type is not forced to contain the entire prototype tree up to and including that of Object. I mean I see why a function would be treated differently, but It does feel inconsistent to me.

Comment: Regarding the answer, thanks but I'd rather leave it open for a bit in the hope of a solution. I have got rid of the errors in the code. Thanks guys.

Comment: Related issue: [microsoft/TypeScript#29261](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29261), request to be able to map a call signature without the other function properties, currently not possible

Comment: @jcalz Interesting. I also found this one. https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27575 So at least I'm not alone :-).

Comment: @jcalz - okay - i guess I will have to make do with a bunch of nevers in my interface for the time being. Everything else is working like a dream so I guess you win some, you loose some... If you would like to make a summary answer then feel free. If not I will write one myself. If it becomes possible in the future, I'll update.

Answer (score 2):

I found a workaround:

```
declare class SomeName {
  static someField: any;
}

type Identity<T> = T;

interface SomeName extends Identity<typeof SomeName> {
  (...args: any[]): any;
}

const someName: SomeName
```

this solution allows `someName` to be called and the `someField` property to be first in the suggestion list

Comment: Yes - I saw your comment on the GitHub thread. When I get a chance I'll see if this works in my use case. Thanks.